# Subjunctive. Why 2 is correct

Tags: grammar

日本人は  旅行に＿＿＿時 たくさん お土産 を買います。

１・　行く
２・　行った

What is the correct answer?

Comment: Please say which one you think is correct and why. (Also, what do you mean by "subjunctive" in the title? I know about the subjunctive in English, and in some other languages, but I don't understand how it is related to this question.)

Comment: These threads might help, too: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24317/explaining-tense-in-japanese/24325#24325 ・ http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2317/9831

Answer (score 0):

日本人は 旅行に「行く」時たくさんおみやげを買います。

Japanese buy lots of souvenirs before going to trip.

日本人は 旅行に「行った」時たくさんおみやげを買います。

Japanese buy lots of souvenirs when they goes to trip.

Comment: The problem im having is.. Why it has be 行った since the sentence is a habitual of thing. That until now is still happening. I translated it as "Japanese people buys a lot of souvenir when they go on travel" which Perfectly to 行く時。it quite strange to use 行った時 since it 時 is not part of Subjunctive Mood.

Comment: If you say just "They goes on a travel", 「彼らは旅行に行く」.  But if you say "when they goes on travel", 「彼らが旅行に行った時」. Keyword is "when"

Comment: That's my point. If they go ob travel why it has to be past. 行く時 is more seems correct

Comment: Because "they" aren't on the trip when someone talking about "they" ("they" is Japanese people in this topic) at the time.

Comment: The same topic as http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30878/19880

Comment: In English, a similar example (but not exactly the same) is "If I were you, I would do something". In this case, I is not you, that's why use the past sentence.

Comment: It makes sense now. Something wishful and impossible to do in English takes Past tense

Comment: Yes. In Japanese language, if the talk topic is not happened at the time, we use past tense (typically "condition"). That's Japanese grammar rule.